# Devise routing block to create user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How to define devise login logout in routes.rb.
I have

```
<%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete' %>       
 <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path %>
```

I want to create other account by administrator when he logged in.
and i make a form to craete account but when i submit it displays u are already signed in.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what the question is but if you want to first define /logout /login /register routes in routes.rb I would edit the devise_for line in routes.rb to:

devise_for :users do
    get "login", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "logout", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    get "register", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
end

Like that... and then you can use them accordingly.. If this doesn't help please rephrase the question and I can try to assist further.